# Confusing issue with normalize

Tags: glsl

I am follow a guide on ray marching by The Art of Code, and I tried to implement my own ray marcher without looking at the video. I was wondering if I could get some help with my code. My code is below. The confusion it at line 86, which is at the bottom of the code and marked with a comment.

Normalize should not be needed here since the ray_direction is normalized in the RayMarch function. Therefore if the normalize is removed from line 86 nothing should change, yet this is not the case. What is going on here?

```
#define MAX_STEPS 100
#define MAX_DIST 100.
#define SURF_DIST .01


// Signed distance function. Returns shortest distance to surface, negative if inside
float GetDist(vec3 position){
    // Define sphere
    vec3 sphere_position = vec3(0,1,6);
    float sphere_radius = 1.;

    // Distance to ground
    float plane_distance = position.y;

    // Distance to sphere
    float sphere_distance = distance(position, sphere_position) - sphere_radius;


    return min(plane_distance, sphere_distance);
}

// Take ray origin and direction of ray, return distance you can travel along ray before you
// hit an object
float RayMarch(vec3 ro, vec3 rd){
    rd = normalize(rd);

    float marched_distance = 0.;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPS;i++){
        vec3 current_pos = ro + marched_distance * rd;
        float dist = GetDist(current_pos);
        marched_distance += dist;


        if (dist < SURF_DIST || marched_distance > MAX_DIST){
            break;
        }

    }
    return marched_distance;
}



vec3 GetNormal(vec3 position){
    // Gradient of SDF in same direction as normal. We compute using centered difference

    vec2 epsilon_vector = vec2(0.01,0.);

    float x_deriv = ( GetDist(position) - GetDist(position - epsilon_vector.xyy) );
    float y_deriv = ( GetDist(position) - GetDist(position - epsilon_vector.yxy) );
    float z_deriv = ( GetDist(position) - GetDist(position - epsilon_vector.yyx) );


    return normalize(vec3(x_deriv, y_deriv, z_deriv));
}


// Given position, get light intensity (?) by dotting light vector with normal vector. Account
// for shadow by marching from point towards light and seeing if distance received is shorter than
// absolute distance from light (will overshoot if no object in between).
float GetLight(vec3 position){
    vec3 light_pos = vec3(0, 5, 6);
    light_pos += 2.*vec3(cos(iTime),0,sin(iTime));

    // Modify position so ray marcher doesn't immediately terminate
    vec3 modified_p = position + SURF_DIST*2.*GetNormal(position);

    float march_dist = RayMarch(modified_p, light_pos - position);

    float intensity = clamp(dot(normalize(light_pos - position), GetNormal(position)),0.,1.);

    if (march_dist < length(light_pos - position)){
        intensity *= 0.1;
    }
    return intensity;
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec3 camera_pos = vec3(0,1,0);
    vec3 screen_pos = vec3(0,1,1);


    vec2 uv = (fragCoord - iResolution.xy*.5)/iResolution.yy;

    vec3 pixel_coord = vec3(uv,0) + screen_pos;

    vec3 ray_direction = normalize(pixel_coord - camera_pos); // This line is causing the confusion

    float dist = RayMarch(camera_pos, ray_direction);

    float light = GetLight(camera_pos + ray_direction * dist);

    vec3 col = vec3(light);

    fragColor = vec4(col,1.);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the call to `RayMarch` is this line:

> ```
> float light = GetLight(camera_pos + ray_direction * dist);
> ```

This *also* uses `ray_direction`, and this code makes no sense if `ray_direction` is not normalized.

The normalization in `RayMarch` is applied to the parameter of `RayMarch`. This parameter is a local variable, and is not declared as an `out` or `inout` parameter, so it *cannot* affect the contents of the `ray_direction` variable that was used to initialize the parameter.

So `ray_direction` will remain unnormalized, and thus this code becomes dysfunctional.